# Cómo pasar argumento de main a una función en C

Tags: c

¿Cómo puedo pasar el argumento `char*` argv desde `main` a una función para que esta cree un fichero txt con el nombre que le pasas por línea de comandos?

Main:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
  if(argc==0||argc>=2){
    printf("Uso: ./discos fichero_discos\n");
    return 0;
  }


lectura(&argv[]);}
```

Función:

```
void lectura(struct Disco **primero,struct Disco **ultimo,char* argv[]){
    char linea[512];
    struct Disco *auxl;

    pf = fopen(argv[], "r");

  if(pf==NULL){
    pf = fopen(argv[], "w");
    fclose(pf);
  }
  while(fgets(linea,sizeof(linea),pf)!=NULL){
        auxl=(struct Disco*)malloc(sizeof(struct Disco));
    if(*primero==NULL){
        *primero=auxl;
        *ultimo=auxl;
    }else{
        (*ultimo)->sig=auxl;
        *ultimo=auxl;
    }
sscanf(linea,"%s %s %i %s %f", auxl->titulo,auxl->artista,&auxl->fecha,auxl->formato,&auxl->precio);
auxl=auxl->sig;
  }
  fclose(pf);
}
```

Esa es la función con su `main`, debería crear un fichero con el nombre que elija el usuario.

Obviando los punteros "Primero" y "Ultimo" que pertenecen a otras funciones.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una variable de tipo `int` y tienes que llamar a una función que recibe un `int` ¿Cómo lo haces? Lo pasas tal cual:

```
int var;

func(var);
```

Pues en tu caso tienes un argumento de tipo `char *[]` y esa variable se la tienes que pasar a una función que espera un tipo `char *[]`... es exactamente lo mismo:

```
Disco ** primero = /* ... */;
Disco ** ultimo  = /* ... */;
lectura(primero, ultimo, argv);
```

No te dejes apabullar por los punteros dobles o triples, si los tipos son iguales la llamada es directa.

Ahora bien, si únicamente te interesa uno de los parámetros de `argv` y no todos, como le estás pasando ahora mismo, puedes simplificar un poco la función:

```
char* nombreFichero = argv[1]; // O el indice que sea
lectura(primero, ultimo, nombreFichero);

void lectura(struct Disco **primero,struct Disco **ultimo,char* nombreFichero);
```

Comment: Y la propia función Lectura? Qué argumentos debe esperar? Con tu solución se produce un error de compilación. El error en concreto es que "Lectura tiene demasiados argumentos"  Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estás pasando a la función el argv por referencia, y realmente el prototipo de la función espera simplemente un char*. Te sobra, por tanto, el "&".

En el caso de los otros parámetros, al esperar la función "lectura" dos struct Disco**, si en el main() tienes struct Disco* sí se mandaría con &.

Comment: No está pasando nada por referencia: [tag:c] no tiene referencias.